# multiple ggplot in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, plot

I have dataset in R as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20 * 5, mean = 0, sd = 1), 20, 5))
colnames(data) <- c("Y", paste0("X", 1:4))
```

and I want to create all possible plots between `Y` and `X`'s. For a simple plot I can do this:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in seq(ncol(data))[-1]) {
  plot(data[, 1], data[, i], xlab = colnames(data)[i], ylab = "Y")
}
```

How can create the equivalent plots based on `ggplot` function. I created the following but I can not make it work.

```
par(mflow = c(2,2))
for (i in seq(ncol(data))[-1]){
ggplot(data, aes(x = data[,i], y = data[,1])) +
  labs(x = colnames(data)[i], y = "Y") +
  stat_smooth() +
  geom_point(color = "gray40", alpha = .5)
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `ggplot2` you are most of the time better off by reshaping your data to long or tidy format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. After doing so you could e.g. use `facet_wrap` to get you plots for each X:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_long <- pivot_longer(data, -Y, names_to = "name", values_to = "value")

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value, y = Y)) +
  stat_smooth() +
  geom_point(color = "gray40", alpha = .5) +
  facet_wrap(~name)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]